# Create a class instance on Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a class instance on `Application_Start` that can be used in all controllers?

I would like to be able to create for example:

```
var globalHelper = new LoadsStuff();
```

and then in my Action methods:

```
globalHelper.GetInfoFor("key");
```

My Helper class loads a fairly big XML file to memory and I would like to do that only once.

Comment: Are you using MVC? If you are, you should indicate that in your tags.

Comment: I did but a admin change the tags to asp.net, I just fixed :)

Comment: this sound suspiciously like you want to use dependency injection. have a look at ninject mvc http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/30/dependency-injection-in-nerddinner-app-using-ninject.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use application variables:

```
Application["GlobalHelper"] = new LoadsStuff();

((LoadsStuff) Application["GlobalHelper"]).GetInfoFor("key");
```

---

Refer to:

[ASP.NET Application State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The Application is not available in the controller, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Bjarki Heiðar: Try `HttpContext.Current.Application`.

Comment: It's HttpContext.Application, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put your XML file `Application level object` in `Application_Start` event ?

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Application[""] = //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you can.
I have not tried this, but something like:

```
ManagedWebSessionContext.Bind(HttpContext.Current, globalHelper)
```